# Apache Camel CXF not able to generate Java Classes using wsdl2java generate source?

Tags: maven, apache-camel

My pom.xml is given below

i had build this example from  [here](http://camel.apache.org/tutorial-example-reportincident-part1.html) The generated folder is not getting created in target folder.
I had tried each and every one of the instruction reported below, but the classes are not generating in target folder.

> In this example we're running the `wsdl2java` goal in the
>   generate-sources phase.
>
> By running mvn generate-sources, CXF will generate artifacts in the
>    directory that you specify. Each  element
>   corresponds to a WSDL that you're generated artifacts for. The WSDL
>   location is specified via the `<wsdl>` option.
>
> Following Maven standard directory layout, if you're planning on
>   packaging the WSDL in the JAR you're creating you'll want the WSDL
>   above in /src/main/resources/ (alternatively in a subfolder underneath
>   it if desired to avoid placing resources in the root of a JAR); else
>   use the /src/main/config folder to keep the WSDL out of the JAR.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-example-reportincident</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>Camel Web Application</name>
  <description>Camel project that deploys the Camel routes as a WAR</description>
  <url>http://www.myorganization.org</url>

  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <cxf-version>2.7.0</cxf-version>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>release.fusesource.org</id>
      <name>FuseSource Release Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
    </repository>
    <repository>
     <id>ea.fusesource.org</id>
     <name>FuseSource Community Early Access Release Repository</name>
     <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
     <snapshots>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
     </snapshots>
     <releases>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
     </releases>
    </repository>    
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>release.fusesource.org</id>
      <name>FuseSource Release Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
     <id>ea.fusesource.org</id>
     <name>FuseSource Community Early Access Release Repository</name>
     <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
     <snapshots>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
     </snapshots>
     <releases>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
     </releases>
    </pluginRepository>      
  </pluginRepositories>

 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-stream</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.1</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>       
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis-jaxrpc</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis-saaj</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>axis</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis-wsdl4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
    <version>0.4</version>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>

        <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0pre3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${basedir}\target\generated\</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>${basedir}\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\wsdl\report_incident.wsdl</wsdl>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: I had build this example by refering to this [camel example](http://camel.apache.org/tutorial-example-reportincident-part1.html).

Answer (score 0):

In many of my projects I had the same requirement and usually I used a pom like this:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>generate-sources</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <wsdlOptions>
                        <wsdlOption>
                            <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/Authentication.wsdl</wsdl>
                            <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/Authentication.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                            <extraargs>
                                <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                            </extraargs>
                        </wsdlOption>                               
                    </wsdlOptions>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

and classes have been successfully created in the target folder.

I'm using version 3.0.4 but I'm sure this worked also with 2.x versions.

I think that you're missing the `-client` extraarg:

```
<extraargs>
    <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
</extraargs>
```

and, more important, you can omit the `<sourceRoot>` tag thus leaving the default value. More references [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164522/cxf-codegen-plugin-doesnt-generate-sources).

Comment: Updated. Try removing the <sourceRoot> tag.

Comment: i tried by removing <sourceRoot> tag but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Try using forward slash (/) instead of backward slash (\) i.e.

```
<configuration>
           <sourceRoot>${basedir}/target/generated/cxf/</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/wsdl/report_incident.wsdl</wsdl>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: I have edit the sourceRoot path, can you try with it.